# Tracking coding tools along with source code

Tags: git, svn, maven, development-environment, projects-and-solutions

The project I work on has a giant repository (think SVN), with our source code, DLL dependencies, build tools (from Qmake to custom GUI builders), and user scripts all stuffed into a tree of directories. When a developer wants to set up a computer for developing, they would install Visual Studio and Eclipse, and then pull all the necessary development tools from the repository. If it's not needed, it isn't pulled.

We're moving to Git for our source code. It works quite well, and we've been happy with the tests we've done. My problem is that we can't move away from our giant repository until we figure out how to handle all our tools. Git currently only contains the source code and scripts relevant to each project. We've broken up the project into smaller Git repositories to make it sensible for a developer to clone only the necessary projects, but we still have the problem of these tools.

So my question is this: how do users of Git manage their tools? If an older version of your build scripts require Qmake v1.0, while the current version requires Qmake 2.0, how do you deal with that? Is it reasonable to add smaller binary tools to the repository, knowing that the cloning operation will download every old version? It worries me that a new developer can't check out an older version of the source code and compile; they'll have to also know how which dev tools are required. As we're in the process of upgrading dev tools, this is an important consideration.

The tools don't change very often, but they do sometimes change. They aren't so big, but I hate the idea of them being in Git. The project is quite old, so we have a lot of "helper programs" which are used for maintenance of the data or sub-tasks a client might want to do.

#### Possible Solutions

1. **Maven** - I have no experience with this, but I like the idea of defining a project "dependency configuration" file that Maven uses to pull relevant binaries from a server.
2. **Shared drive** on the server, filled with all relevant tools. Use them directly on the server - the downside is that if the server goes off-line, all work stops. Maybe the developer has to manually copy the tools he uses? This would be annoying.
3. **SVN** for our tools, Git for our source code. But then we may as well just use SVN for everything, to reduce complexity. A developer can use Git as an SVN client, if desired.

Any ideas? How do you do it?

Comment: An unpleasant, unlikeable technique I have experience with (it works, but it's "un", as noted): use submodules containing the relevant binaries.

Comment: @torek, that's not a bad idea. As long as the submodules don't change so often, maybe that'll work for us. Do you have a recommendation on how to avoid (or minimize) all the "un"? I've got some experience with submodules for code dependencies, which was a painful experience. Maybe Git has grown since I tried that...

Comment: No ... I escaped :-) from that situation and have been avoiding submodules since then.

Comment: How about git subtree?

Comment: @Shunya, that seems similar to submodule, but slightly more weird. Maybe if someone with experience can tell me if it works well, I can give it a shot. One problem I have is that Git already has a steep learning curve. Subtree seems a bit more complicated than submodule, since a submodule can be treated as a separate repository (and updated quickly from the parent when the reference needs to be updated). I have a lot of Git experience, but my coworkers do not.

Comment: @jmbeck, I have not used git subtree till now, but have heard that it is a good alternative to git submodule,  here is a atlassian blog which narrates git subtree (http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/), there are many available on the net.

Answer (score 1):

There is another class of software which is designed to help such administrative tasks such as puppet, chef, vagrant. The tools allow to describe environments by special kind of scripts (recipes) and then to set up all software automatically.

Comment: Huh. I did not know about these tools. Vagrant seems particularly useful for building testing VM's. Good to know! I'm not sure how I'd be able easily integrate it into our workflow, but I'll keep it in mind.